# Reducing order of quadratic eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider
$$(\lambda^2 \mathbb{M} +2ic\lambda \mathbb{K}+\mu \mathbb{C})\vec{A}=0, \quad \quad (1)$$

where $$\mathbb{M}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \mu     &  1+\mu\\
    1+\mu      & \mu \\
\end{bmatrix}; \quad \quad
\mathbb{K}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0    &  -1\\
    1      & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix};\quad \quad
\mathbb{C}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1     &  1\\
    1      & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix},$$

and $\nu=-4 a^2, \mu =\nu(1-2a^2), c=\sqrt{1-4a^2}$, for $a\in \mathbb{R}^+$, and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue with associated eigenvector $\vec{A}=(A,A^*)$ for $A$ a complex number.

I can go through the algebra to find

$$\lambda^2=-\frac{4(1-6a^2)}{(1-4a^2)^2}.$$

Which implies that $\lambda$ comes in pairs. This is a simplified example of a much larger system, where I'll be solving this numerically and would gain a lot by only having to solve for 1/2 the eigenvalues.

My question is, can I rewrite/manipulate equation (1) so that the term in parentheses becomes diagonal diagonalized (possibly times other matrices which change the form of $\vec{A}$? Generally, I know how to do this in an ordinary eigenvalue problem, but do not see how to obviously proceed here.

Comment: In the general scenario, is it guaranteed that$$M,C,K\in\mathrm M_{2×2}(\mathbb R),\ M^T=M,\ C^T=C$$ or $$M,C,K\in\mathrm M_{2×2}(\mathbb C),\ M^*=M,\ C^*=C?$$

Comment: @AlexFrancisco In general M, C are symmetric, i.e. $M=M^T, C=C^T$.